# Базы данных

Tags: nosql, sql

Здравствуйте. Начинаю разрабатывать проект и боюсь прогадать. Планируется много данных и пользователей (связей между пользователями не будет). Какие базы данных выбрать для хранения данных. Если бы я использовал какую-либо sql базу, то количество добавленных записей в таблицах за один день может превышать десятки и сотни тысяч. Или это не страшно и можно юзать Sql ?

Comment: тысячи записей в день будут из-за большого количества пользователей. И вы посчитали только записи в базу, а чтение из базы?

Comment: расскажите больше - может и понятно будет.

Но иногда полезно разделить базы. Например, всякую статистику/счетчики вынести в MongoDB - она с этим хорошо умеет справляться, а если и упадет... не страшно. Зато основную базу можно разгрузить сильно.

Comment: Вы не первый, кто задается этим вопросом, в том числе и на этом форуме: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=sql+nosql&t=question

Answer (score 1):

Если нормально спроектировать, то конечно не страшно. nosql решения не всегда быстрее или лучше. 100к записей в день - это всего то 11 запросов в секунду.

Рекомендую сесть с листиком и все посчитать. Причем в трех вариантах - пессимистичном, среднем и оптимистичном. Потом вопросы пропадут.

Берите любую базу - MySql (или MariaDB) или PostgreSQL и пробуйте.

Но думаю, что там вряд ли будут тысячи записей в день, если только не перемудрили с проектированием.